# Reference a prototype function in the constructor, how?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a JavaScript game using Phaser.js but I'm running into some sort of scoping issue and I don't know how to solve it.

When the player wins a `ResultPanel` appears with the score and some buttons. The player can press the buttons to go to the next level or reset etc. The code to handle back/reset/next is in prototype functions, but those aren't yet defined when the constructor is called(?).

At is it now, the function `doBtnBack` is never called when I press the button.
What am I doing wrong? What's the right way to do this?

```
// level complete panel constructor
ResultPanel = function(game, stars) {

    this.game = game;

    // display how many yellow stars
    var star1 = stars > 0 ? 'star_yellow' : 'star_grey';
    var star2 = stars > 1 ? 'star_yellow' : 'star_grey';
    var star3 = stars > 2 ? 'star_yellow' : 'star_grey';

    // add text and stars
    this._panelCaption = this.game.add.bitmapText(144, 12, 'bigrigsfont', 'you are winner!', 48);
    this._panelStar1   = this.game.add.sprite(300-160, 144, 'buttonicon', star1);
    this._panelStar2   = this.game.add.sprite(300,     144, 'buttonicon', star2);
    this._panelStar3   = this.game.add.sprite(300+160, 144, 'buttonicon', star3);

    // add button icons
    // NOTE: below code runs but something is wrong because
    // this.doBtnBack this.doBtnReset etc. is undefined
    this.btnBack  = this.game.add.button(300-100, 300, 'buttonicon', this.doBtnBack,  this, 'back_grey',  'back_hl');
    this.btnReset = this.game.add.button(300,     300, 'buttonicon', this.doBtnReset, this, 'reset_grey', 'reset_hl');
    this.btnNext  = this.game.add.button(300+100, 300, 'buttonicon', this.doBtnNext,  this, 'next_grey',  'next_hl');

};

ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnBack = function() {
    console.log('Panel button BACK pressed') // never reaches here
};

ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnReset = function() {
    console.log('Panel button RESET pressed');
};

ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnNext = function() {
    console.log('Panel button NEXT pressed');
};
```

I also tried this, but that gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.doBtnBack is not a function`

```
this.btnBack  = this.game.add.button(300-100, 300, 'buttonicon', function(){this.doBtnBack();},  this, 4, 0, 8);
```

Comment: Don't see where's `this.game` defined(sould be undefined)? You can use `game`(without `this`) which comes from arguments, or assign `this.game = game` in the beginning of `ResultPanel `.

Comment: I tried to put only relevant code in the question but forgot to add `this.game = game;`, now added

Comment: It it possible that `ResultPanel` is called without `new`? Could you make `console.log(this)` inside constructor?

Comment: The `new` keyword is used, so when I log `this` to the console in the constructor it shows `ResultPanel > _bounds: c.Rectangle _cacheAsBitmap: false etc.` as expected

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually use a MyGame prefix/namespace on all my objects, because that's also used in [this code example](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-phaser-building-monster-wants-candy--cms-21723). I admit I don't quite know what that the `MyGame.` does precisely.

So my code actually looks like this:

```
var MyGame = {};

MyGame.Bootup = function() {
//etc.
MyGame.GameState = function() {
    create: function() {
        var panel = new MyGame.ResultPanel(this, 3);
    }
};
```

And see the panel object code below. Now, if I remove all the `MyGame.` from the code below but keep it in the code above (except in the var panel = new ResultPanel(this, 3)" then it works(?). No clue why that is.

```
// level complete panel constructor
MyGame.ResultPanel = function(game, stars) {

    this.game = game;
    // etc.
};

MyGame.ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnBack = function() {
    console.log('Panel button BACK pressed') // never reaches here
};

MyGame.ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnReset = function() {
    console.log('Panel button RESET pressed');
};

MyGame.ResultPanel.prototype.doBtnNext = function() {
    console.log('Panel button NEXT pressed');
};

// level complete panel constructor
MyGame.GameState = function() {
    create: function() {
        var panel = new MyGame.ResultPanel(this, 3);
    }
};
```